# Tensorflow low train/test accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I restored a pre-trained model in Tensorflow 1.2 to do some testing work. I assumed the model was well-trained since the loss decreased to very low (0.0001). However, with either the testing samples or training samples, the accuracy ops give me a value which is almost 0. Is this because I'm using the wrong accuracy function or is it because the model is the problem?

Here is the accuracy function, the `test_image` below is a batch with a single test sample, `test_image_label` is a single label:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(GoogleNet(test_image), 1), tf.argmax(test_image_label, 0))
accuracy = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)

with Session() as less:
    accuracy_vector = []
    for num in range(len(testnames)):
        accuracy_vector.append(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={keep_prob: 1.0}))
    print(accuracy_vector)
    mean_accuracy = sess.run(tf.divide(tf.add_n(accuracy_vector), len(testnames)))
    print("test accuracy %g"%mean_accuracy)
```

The model is defined as `GoogleNet(data)` above, it is a function that returns the logits of the input batch. The training was done like this:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=train_label_batch, logits=GoogleNet(train_batch)))
train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)
```

The `train_step` is ran in every iteration. I think it is worth noting that after restored the model, I cannot run `print(GoogleNet(test_image).eval(feed_dict={keep_prob: 1.0}))` in the session, with which I intended to take a look at the output of the model. It returns the error of `FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_213
     [[Node: Variable_213/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_213"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_213)]]`

Comment: Why is there tf.argmax(test_image_label, 0) and not tf.argmax(test_image_label, 1)?

Comment: That's because test_image_label is a single label that was not batched, so it's a scaler